# PHP data from route in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, smarty, ngroute

I am sending a variable to a PHP file as a parameter on a route with AngularJS. The PHP file then returns an array of objects in a Smarty variable that I would like to use in a normal ng-repeat in the new view that is loaded. How can this be accomplished? I have looked into http, resolve, promises, resolve+RequireJS lazy loading. I can not figure out the best way to accomplish this, let alone a way that functions at all. Heck at this point I'd even use a hack if it functioned.

The problem is that in the `myProjects` controller, if I define the Smarty variable returned from my PHP file, that data will not be available until AFTER the route with the userId parameter has been called, so it throws an `undefined` error and kills the entire script.

Any suggestions very much appreciated!

```
\$routeProvider
        // route for a clients projects
        .when('/clientprojects/:userId', {
            templateUrl : function(params){ return '/dealer-admin/clients?tpl=true&data='+params.userId; },
            controller  : 'myProjects'
        })
```

Comment: I dont understand. Do you have a problem fetching the data or displaying the data?

Comment: I can send the parameter like I do above, then fetch data based on the param, then return and display it with a smarty variable in the new view. The problem is that I can not use this smarty variable in the myProjects controller after it has been fetched, so the fetched data is basically worthless to me. If I can't use that Smarty variable in the myProjects controller then I can't use it in ng-repeat, I can't filter it, I essentially can't manipulate it in the view in any way. I need to figure out how to return it all the way back to my angular app, not just echo a smarty variable in the view